# MySQL Bulk Insert for relational table from MS.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, bulk-load

I want to perform bulk insert from CSV to MySQL database using C#, I'm using **MySql.Data.MySqlClient** for connection. CSV columns are refereed into multiple tables and they are dependent on primary key value, for example,

CSV(column & value): -

```
emp_name, address,country
-------------------------------
jhon,new york,usa
amanda,san diago,usa
Brad,london,uk
```

DB Schema(CountryTbl) & value

```
country_Id,Country_Name
1,usa
2,UK
3,Germany
```

DB Schema(EmployeeTbl)

```
Emp_Id(AutoIncrement),Emp_Name
```

DB Schema(AddressTbl)

```
Address_Id(AutoIncrement), Emp_Id,Address,countryid
```

**Problem statement:**

1> Read data from CSV to get the CountryId from "CountryTbl" for respective employee.

2> Insert data into EmployeeTbl and AddressTbl with CountryId

**Approach 1**

Go as per above problem statement steps, but that will be a performance hit (Row-by-Row read and insert)

**Approach 2**

Use "Bulk Insert" option "**MySqlBulkLoader**", but that needs csv files to read, and looks that this option is not going to work for me.

**Approach 3**

Use stored proc and use the procedure for upload. But I don't want to use stored proc.

Please suggest if there is any other option by which I can do bulk upload or suggest any other approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have hundreds of thousands of rows to upload, bulk loading (your approach 2) probably is not worth the extra programming and debugging time it will cost.  That's my opinion, for what it's worth (2x what you paid for it :)

Approaches 1 and 3 are more or less the same. The difference lies in whether you issue the queries from c# or from your sp. You still have to work out the queries. So let's deal with 1.

The solutions to these sorts of problems depend on make and model of RDBMS. If you decide you want to migrate to SQL Server, you'll have to change this stuff.

Here's what you do. For each row of your employee csv ...

... Put a row into the employee tbl

```
 INSERT INTO EmployeeTbl (Emp_Name) VALUES (@emp_name);
```

Notice this query uses the `INSERT ... VALUES` form of the insert query.  When this query (or any insert query) runs, it drops the autoincremented `Emp_Id` value where a subsequent invocation of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` can get it.

... Put a row into the address table

```
INSERT INTO AddressTbl (Emp_Id,Address,countryid)
     SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS Emp_Id, 
            @address AS Address, 
            country_id AS countryid
       FROM CountryTbl
      WHERE Country_Name = @country;
```

Notice this second INSERT uses the `INSERT ... SELECT` form of the insert query. The `SELECT` part of all this generates one row of data with the column values to insert.

- It uses `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get `Emp_Id`,
- it uses a constant provided by your C# program for the `@address`, and
- it looks up the `countryid` value from your pre-existing `CountryTbl`.

Notice, of course, that you must use [the C# `Parameters.AddWithValue()` method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html) to set the values of the `@` parameters in these queries. Those values come from your CSV file.

Finally, wrap each thousand rows or so of your csv in a [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html), by preceding their INSERT statements with a `START TRANSACTION;` statement and ending them with a `COMMIT;` statement.  That will get you a performance improvement, and if something goes wrong the entire transaction will get rolled back so you can start over.

Comment: In case of oracle, loading data into external tables using SP and then reading that table in batches through code for further processing (validation, insertion) add any advantage ?